# AWS-IoT-Core / Device Shadow: Use more than one shadow_property in the AWS-IoT-Device-SDK for Python

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core

The AWS-IoT-Device-SDK for Python contains the sample file "shadow.py".
In this file I can only specify **one shadow_property** like "color".

```
[...]
cmdUtils.register_command("shadow_property", "<str>", "The name of the shadow property you want to change (optional, default='color'", default="color")
[...]
shadow_property = cmdUtils.get_command("shadow_property")
[...]
```

**Do any of you have an idea to use more than one shadow properties like "color", "status" etc?**

I can start and run the script several times, but it isn't handy.

**Source:**

- [Sample File shadow.py on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/shadow.py)
- https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
request = iotshadow.UpdateShadowRequest(
        thing_name=shadow_thing_name,
        state=iotshadow.ShadowState(
            reported={ 'color': 'blue',
                       'status': 'connected' }
            ),
            client_token=token,
        )
```